# Informal spoken English: I shall wait you in the garden, five o'clock

Tags: archaic-language, informal-language, spoken-english

Is the sentence in the title, "I shall wait you in the garden, five o'clock," grammatical, even though it might be archaic?

Comment: 'await' is archaic & would work in that sentence, in an archaic way. Modern you would have to use 'wait for' & probably also 'at 5 o'clock'

Comment: @Tetsujin are you saying that 'wait', wouldn't work even in an archaic way? (as opposed to 'await')

Comment: Neither *wait* nor *await* is archaic.

Comment: @δοῦλος I mean "wait" without the following "for".

Comment: Okay, I see now. I dunno if *wait* was used like this. I don't have access to the Oxford English Dictionary at the moment. It's not common to say *await a person*, at least not nowadays.

Comment: Are questions about archaic forms really on-topic here? I was under the impression that this site is for people trying to learn modern English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about current uses of modern English. We aren't specialists in archaic forms, only in modern.

Comment: I'm not sure that "is this sentence perhaps archaic?" is off-topic. I think that the question could be made clearer however - is the question "Is this grammatical, even though it might be archaic?" or is the question "I want to use an archaic form, is this correct?".

Comment: @ColleenV You hit the nail on the head. What I meant was "Is this grammatical, even though it might be archaic?"

Comment: Well, then, no it's not grammatical in contemporary English, even though it *might* be archaic.

Comment: @δοῦλος Thank you! You may add it as an answer. By the way, before I asked this question, I searched Google Ngram without success (no results). But when I change "you" to "your" (despite "your" being irrelevant to my question), it gives interesting results: http://i.imgur.com/Hpga51q.png

Comment: Yes, older usages such as *I shall wait your pleasure/orders/command/answer* suggests *wait* was once used similarly to how *await* is currently used.

Comment: From the OED's entry for *wait*: "**5. a.** *trans.* To look forward (esp. with desire or apprehension) to (some future event or contingency); to continue in expectation of. Now somewhat *rare*: usually superseded by **await v.**"  I don't think it's really used anymore, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is not grammatical in contemporary English, even though it *might* be archaic

Comment: As @snailplane noted, it is archaic: "From the OED's entry for wait: "5. a. trans. To look forward (esp. with desire or apprehension) to (some future event or contingency); to continue in expectation of. Now somewhat rare: usually superseded by await v." I don't think it's really used anymore, though."